# why unique in schema mongoose not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

unique is not working in schema.

i have two problems.
1_in schema unique is not working.i deleted all data in db and tryed again but it doesn't work.
my codes :

`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username :{type : String , unique :true , required : true},
    email:{type : String , required : true , unique :true},
    password:{type : String , required : true},
    isadmin:{type : Boolean , default:false},
},{timestamps:true})
```

`

`

```
//register
router.post('/register' ,async (req , res )=>{
    const newUser = new User({
        username:req.body.username,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:cryptoJS.AES.encrypt(req.body.password , process.env.pass_key)
    })

    try {
        const saveduser =await newUser.save()
        res.status(201).json(saveduser)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error)
    }
})
```

`

2.where can i find all schema options? like unique and require and etc.
thanks for your attention.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#unique-doesnt-work
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#options
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Schema

Answer (score 0):

```
const schema2 = new Schema({
  test: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    unique: true // Unique index. If you specify `unique: true`
    // specifying `index: true` is optional if you do `unique: true`
  }
});
```

*It will throw error like this and you can can handle by error code 11000*

Error:
**{"name":"MongoError","code":11000,"err":"insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: mydb.users.$email_1  dup key: { : null }"}**